# grails 3 overriding queryForResource not working

Tags: rest, grails, resources, nested, url-mapping

According to [Grails Web Services](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/webServices.html)

I can override the method [queryForResource](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.0/api/grails/rest/RestfulController.html#queryForResource(java.io.Serializable)). This way I may be able to specify nested REST resource. e.g

```
"/authors"(resources:'author') {
    "/books"(resources:'book')
}
```

But the doc may be wrong. Because it uses an assigment operator **=** instead a comparison one **==**.

Running This way I get the following error:

```
((id == id) && building.id) is a binary expression, but it should be a variable expression
```

Changing the operator from **=** to **==** I get another error

```
Cannot query property "params" - no such property on class clash.BuildingLevel exists
```

What is the correct way to define this nested REST resource?

Here is my queryForResource method:

I tried both:

```
@Override
protected BuildingLevel queryForResource(Serializable id) {
    if (params.buildingId) {
        return BuildingLevel.where {
            id == id && building.id = params.buildingId
        }.find()
    }
}


@Override
protected BuildingLevel queryForResource(Serializable id) {
    if (params.buildingId) {
        return BuildingLevel.where {
            id == id && building.id == params.buildingId
        }.find()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your queryForResource method?

Comment: Hi @SandeepPoonia. I posted 2 forms of the method I tried without success

Answer (score 1):

I just figure it out.

The following post [issues-posting-nested-resource-in-grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961909/issues-posting-nested-resource-in-grails) helped me.

The **params** cannot be inside the **where clause**. So It's necessary to create a local variable to keep the value. Like this:

```
@Override
protected BuildingLevel queryForResource(Serializable id) {
    def myLocalVariablebuildingId = params.buildingId
    if (params.buildingId) {
        return BuildingLevel.where {
            id == id && building.id == myLocalVariablebuildingId
        }.find()
    }
}
```